# Accessing a sybase db file

Tags: sybase

I Have a sybase sql anywhere '.db' file that is typically run on a database server engine. Is there anything out there that would let me just view the .db file without this server? I'm having so much trouble connecting to it and the command line tools dont even help much

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the only thing that can read data from a SQL Anywhere database file is the SQL Anywhere server. If you are having problems with the server or the utilities, you can ask about them over at http://sqlanywhere-forum.sybase.com/.

*Disclaimer: I work at Sybase in SQL Anywhere engineering.*